# SVN Update in Post Commit - [Firing, but no results]

Tags: svn, batch-file, hook

This is my post-commit.bat hook script for SVN.

But my working copy is not updated automatically after the commit has happened.

However, if I manually open this file. Everything works as expected.

Please guide me.

```
@echo off

cls
echo == Initiating system instance variables...
echo. -- Setting the variables...

:: Here you need to make some changes to suit your system.
set SOURCE=C:\Users\subbarao.b\Desktop\SVNRepo
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\

:: Unless you want to modify the script, this is enough.

echo. %SOURCE%
echo. %SVN%
echo. ++ Done setting variables.
echo.
echo == Updating source from SVN
echo. -- Running update...
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
echo. ++ Done.

echo. -- Cleaning up...
set SOURCE=
set SVN=
echo. ++ Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never** use TortoiseProc in hooks: it's GUI program, which can not be executed in text-only console

```
%SVN%\svn up -q %SOURCE%
```

will work on any terminal (add CLI SVN-tools from TortoiseSVN installation, if you still haven't it)

From [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html)

> If the post-commit hook returns a nonzero exit status, the commit will
>   not be aborted since it has already completed. However, anything that
>   the hook printed to stderr will be marshalled back to the client,
>   making it easier to diagnose hook failures

I can suggest

- Forcibly return ERROR
- Use `svn up` with redirection of stdout to stderr
- Inspect output

Comment: Tried it, no difference.
The hook is triggered. But no progress is shown at client side commit window.

Comment: @user3686904 do *any* of the `echo` statements appear? In other words, does the batch file even run?

Comment: Nope, there is no signs of any command prompt window opening at all. :(

Comment: @Lazy Badger, Hi, when I try to update my workingcopy using SharpSVN (C#) I do get a '-1' output. But no description of error. Could you help me in getting the error message ?